# I'm looking for some JQuery to run a fairly elaborate drop-down selection/go function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu made up of unordered lists containing several options. Upon selection of an option, I want this option to populate the head selection box (li class="first") replacing the "I am a..." text. Then the "Go" button can be pressed to open the href for that specific option. Here is the html:

```
    <div class="dropNavOne" class="gradient">
    <ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">I am a...</a>
        <ul class="menu_body1">
            <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option 9</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#">Option 10</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><div class="goButtonOne" class="gradient">Go</div></a>
```

If this is at all possible please let me know...thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Look up show and hide. http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

Comment: I think you need to pay someone to do this for you, or learn how to code first. The answer to your question is trivial.

Comment: Then why bother answering Nick? I am new to JQuery and have yet to come across anything that is similar to this situation. If you have any real suggestions then by all means, if not then...well...use your imagination.

Comment: @Lars: don't worry about the initial _baptism of fire_ here. It's hard for seasoned users to strike the right balance between encouraging a good first go and being helpful! If you give my ideas a try, roughly in the order of my points, feel free to then edit in your JS code and ping me here. We may even be able to re-open your question, if you still need assistance at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few pointers that you'll find useful in writing this. There may be plugins that directly fit your requirements, but on the other hand it sounds simple enough that you could do this yourself.

- Use classes for hidden and revealed elements in your unordered list
- Set up a DOM ready handler to add event handlers to your page
- Attach a click event to show your menu (probably by class, so you can show many items in one go)
- Attach a click event to hide your menu
- Use an html injection method to modify the inner HTML of an element

You can certainly use jQuery for this. It's lovely to work with, and writing something like this would be a good first exercise.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth response halfer. This was very helpful.